# What is the minimum memory footprint for a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-4.0

I know that this is an extremely open-ended question but, I'm hoping to just get a baseline idea of where it begins.  I know a few of the several number of things that can affect it's size as I develop.  What I'm just hoping to know it's baseline overhead to see if it's an acceptable option for my application's requirements.

Comment: Why not just create a WPF project, run it and see what kind of resources it uses.

Comment: I did and I tried to use the Performance & diagnostic tools to determine the actual usage but my VS IDE just kept crashing.  I figure that it's overhead should be a known number but, I've googled for about 20 min and cannot find an answer.

Comment: @AlexPearlstein Lazy initialization of all sorts of things when needed effectively means there won't be a constant overhead; it'll be depending on what you're actually using.

Comment: Oh and the simple default main window is about 17k in the task manager but, I know that can be an inaccurate measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A WPF application from VS2013 using .NET 4.5.1 with debug turned off in 32bit mode used 26.6mb of RAM.

The same WPF application launched directly from the non-debug .exe used 14mb of RAM.

This is a boiler plate WPF application with no other DLLs and no logic besides the default code that is generated when you select a WPF application from the new project window.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer.